# Python MySQL Connector not inserting

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

So here is my code. I don't know why insert isn't working. A select statement works. It doesn't fail the try catch either leading me to believe the query is executing. Also entering the insert query manually into MySQL Workbench seems to work fine.

```
def runQuery(query):
    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                       database='optionsdata',
                                       user='python',
                                       passwd='python')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        conn.close()
        cursor.close()
        print(query)
    except Error as e:
        print("Error", e)

def convertDate(date_str):
    date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
    return date_object

ticker = "MSFT"
html = urlopen("https://api.nasdaq.com/api/quote/" + ticker + "/option-chain?assetclass=stocks&todate=2020-05-08&fromdate=2020-04-07&limit=0").read().decode('utf-8')
optionsData = json.loads(html)
rows = optionsData["data"]["optionChainList"]["rows"]

for row in rows:
    call = row["call"]
    expiryDate = convertDate(call["expiryDate"])
    query = "INSERT INTO `optionsdata`.`call` (`ticker`, `symbol`, `last`, `change`, `bid`, `ask`, `volume`, `openinterest`, `strike`, `expiryDate`, `grabTime`) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', '{7}', '{8}', '{9}', '{10}');".format(ticker, call["symbol"], call["last"], call["change"], call["bid"], call["ask"], call["volume"], call["openinterest"], call["strike"], expiryDate, datetime.datetime.now())
    runQuery(query)
```

A sample of what an insert query looks like

```
INSERT INTO `optionsdata`.`call` (`ticker`, `symbol`, `last`, `change`, `bid`, `ask`, `volume`, `openinterest`, `strike`, `expiryDate`, `grabTime`) VALUES ('MSFT', '@MSFT  200508C00175000', '3.21', '-0.29', '2.80', '4.25', '54', '228', '175.00', '2020-05-08', '2020-04-09 19:39:22.554538');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a great question! I spent *hours* trying to figure this out a few weeks ago. It's tricky because after executing the query, you have to call

```py
conn.commit()
```

to actually *update* the data. So change your `runQuery` function like this:

```
def runQuery(query):
    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                       database='optionsdata',
                                       user='python',
                                       passwd='python')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        conn.commit()  # Added commit line
        conn.close()
        cursor.close()
        print(query)
    except Error as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
```

See [this doc page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html) for more info.